# GPU sensor not working, fans out of control

Tags: windows-7, windows, gpu, fan, sensors

My fans are out of control and my GPU is apparently hotter than the surface of the sun.

[image]

I'm using an iMac with Windows 7, (no OS X partition) and I already tried resetting the pram and nvram.

Anything else I could do?

Comment: What does "fans are out of control" mean, and is the system running normal besides these factors?

Comment: Yes it is, but the fans out of control means that they're really loud and such. Spinning out of control. I'm scared they might wear out or something.

Comment: I assume your saying your GPU is showing an unrealistically high temp and not that it "feels" super hot? If thats what your saying, it would seem highly probable that the gpu sensor is faulty, which would also make your fans freak out and try to cool.

Comment: Here's a similar link encase it helps I"ll share it. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2179371?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: That's exactly whats happening, my computer told me it was over 124000 degrees Celsius. For some reason, after the second restart my fans are back to normal, but this is temporary it's happened before and I've restarted like 5 times and they were still freaking out. I'll make sure to check out your link.